# Java recursion and exceptions

Tags: java, exception, recursion

I currently did my programming assignment which was said to use recursion to find the factorial of a number that the user inputs. I successfully did it and it worked, but I decided to expand the code a bit and add an exceptions for kicks.

Basically I want the program to prompt the user to enter a number greater than or equal to 0 and if the user enters a number that is less than 0 I want an exception to be thrown, caught and handled. I know in this code I'm using the incorrect exception which is `StringTooLong`, but I don't know any other exceptions off the top of my head. By the way when I run my code I get an error of cannot find symbol at the `throw lengthException`.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      long userNum;
      System.out.println("Enter a number to check it's factorial");
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      userNum = scnr.nextLong();
      StringTooLongException lengthException =
         new StringTooLongException ("String has too many characters");

      System.out.println(fact(userNum));
   }

   public static long fact(long userNum) {
      try {
         if(userNum < 0) {
            throw lengthException;
         } else if(userNum == 1 || userNum == 0) {
            return 1;
         } else {
            return userNum*fact(userNum-1);
         }
      } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Enter a number that is greater or equal to 0," + e);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) would be a better fit. Also I think you meant to say *"if the user enters a number that is **less** than 0 i want an exception to be thrown".*

Comment: You should be throwing a `new StringTooLongException()`, I believe, not `lengthException`. Or, you could move `lengthException` to the `if` clause.

Comment: The specific error is because the lengthException is out of scope for the method `fact(long userNum)`. Personally I would consider IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
throw new StringTooLongException();
```

And you can remove the following:

```
StringTooLongException lengthException =
new StringTooLongException ("String has too many characters");
```

Though as @KevinO and the others have suggested, it is more suitable to be using [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), e.g.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Or, you could create your own custom `Exception`, e.g.

```
public class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
    public InvalidInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

You have declared `lengthException` in `main`, and tried to use it in `fact`. It is hence out of scope for the method `fact(long userNum)`. Thus the error you got.

You can take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) for more on `exceptions`.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing to include that when you added your comment. I was a bit slow -_-. Please see revised answer, @JonnyHenly

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *new* to fix your throw lengthException error. Also I think you meant to use 'throw new StringTooLongException();'

You should also learn more about what an exception is and what it is used for. One thing is that an Exception is actually a class, and any subclass of the Exception class is itself an Exception. So, if you wanted, you could create your own exception by simply extending the Exception class.  This is why you must use the new keyword when throwing the exception: you are throwing a new instance of an Exception (or one of its subclasses).

You can see a list of some top-level exceptions by exploring the direct known subclasses section in the [JavaDoc for the Exception class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NumberFormatException`:

```
...
if(userNum <= 0) 
{
    throw new NumberFormatException("Must be a positive integer");
}
...
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("Enter a number that is greater or equal to 0," + e);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that that is entirely appropriately: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-faq-what-is-numberformatexception; but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A clean alternative for your implementation is to create your own custom Exception which fits your requirements.

For example, you can create a custom exception class as follows:

```
public class InvalidInputException() extends Exception
{
    public InvalidInputException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This implementation would allow you to `throw new InvalidInputException()` in your try-catch block, and is more informative to the user.